# Can someone explain this simple program below? It rearranges the numbers to be in ascending order for the equation that only contains 1, 2 and 3?

Tags: c++

This program should take in an equation that only consists of 1, 2 and 3s with + operators and rearrange them into ascending order (Codeforces Problem 339A, https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/A) The following below is a working code for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i<s.size(); i+=2){
        for(int k = 0; k<i; k+=2){
            if (s[i] < s[k]){
                std::swap(s[i], s[k]);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<<s << std::endl;
}
```

However, I don't understand this code as when I input 3+2+1, the correct output would be 1+2+3 which it did but shouldn't this program be outputting 2+1+3? Here is what I think about the code.

Input: 3+2+1
Initially, i=0 and k=0 but since the increment occurs at the end of the loop, i remains as 0 and the for loop for k won't run since k is not less than i, thus k will also remain as 0. i then increases by 2 and is now 2, thus the for loop for k will run as 0 < 2 and since s[2] < s[0] (2 < 3), it swaps.

Now s = 2+3+1.

k then increases by 2 and is now 2 and k is no longer lower than i, therefore it exits the loop and i is then increased to 4 now. The outer for loop goes once again since s.size() is 5 and i is 4, causing the inner for loop to run again since k (2) < i (4) and then it swaps the 4th index with the 2nd again of the new s.

s = 2+1+3
i and k gets incremented by 2 again and now i = 6 which is larger than s.size(), thus all the for loops end. However, when I run the program, the answer is 1+2+3 instead. Can anyone spot what is flawed in my thinking? Sorry, I am new to C++ and programming.

Comment: To figure out what exactly happens and how variables change over time you can/should use a debugger and step through the code instruction by instruction and observe the changes. You then can compare the behavior with your mental model about what is happening.

Comment: `causing the inner for loop to run again since k (2) < i (4)` for each iteration of the outer loop the inner loop will always start at `k=0`. But again, for such questions you should use a debugger, you will get your answers way faster using a debugger then waiting for someone to try to find the flaw in your thinking.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will do that next time instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *i* goes 4, *k* returns to 0, *s* = "1+3+2".